# What is more effective against demons, Enervation or Disintegrate

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, wizard, wrath-of-the-righteous

I will hit level 15 with my archmage wizard in the wotr campaign and would like to take spell perfecion. I am not sure though if I should take enervation or disintegrate against demons both is quite powerful at the moment but I am not sure about the endgame level performance of the spells against demons. Since this might depend on the other party members I can tell you that there is a paladin, a arcane trickster and a cleric.

I have persistent, empower, maximize, quickend metamagic feats. But I do not have any abilities to improve the spell's performance. I have a Thanatopic Rod.

Comment: @AnneAunyme Answers go in the answers.

Comment: @harnak Answers go in the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Enervation is stronger.

Both [Enervation](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/enervation/) (4th) and [Disintegrate](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/disintegrate/) (6th) are solid options.

*Enervation* has a few advantages over *Disintegrate*:

- **No saving throw**. This is seriously good, as most demons have *good fortitude saves*, this is a great advantage to have;
- [Negative levels](http://n) make the target easier to kill. The debuffs caused by negative levels are nasty and difficult to remove;
- There is no amount of hp that can save you from the penalties, so if you hit the target (be that an *imp* or a *balor*), they take the penalties;
- More casts per day, being a 4th level spell, you will have more slots available than 6th, and you will have more room to work your metamagic feats.

However, *Disintegrate* has several advantages over *Enervation*:

- Can instantly *kill* the target, this saves actions from the rest of the party. With 30d6 damage, this is nothing to joke about, specially if you mix metamagics;
- Will affect creatures immune to negative levels. Even if you have a [thanatopic rod](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rods/metamagic-rods/metamagic-rod-thanatopic/) or [metamagic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/thanatopic-spell-metamagic/), some creatures will simply ignore the effects of negative levels (like constructs).
- It has a much longer **range**, being a *medium range* spell, it will reach targets 250 feet away, while *Enervation* will hit targets at 60 feet away.

Keep in mind that at level 15, demons around your *average party level* will hardly be killed by a single cast of either of those spells. You should take a look on their sheets and check for vulnerabilities:

- [Nalfeshnee](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/demon/nalfeshnee/). Strong fortitude, low reflex, *Enervation* is better.
- [Marilith](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/demon/marilith/). Really strong fortitude, low will.
- [Seraptis](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/demon/demon-seraptis/). High touch AC, high fortitude.
- [Shemhazian](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/demon/demon-shemhazian/). Moderately high fortitude, low reflex.
- [Vavakia](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/demon/demon-vavakia/). High fortitude, low reflex.

As you can see, the **lowest fortitude save is +19** around your level, which makes *Disintegrate* an unninteresting spell to use, as they will only take 5d6 damage per cast most of the time, and you have better spells to be using your standard action on.